# Getting error in Postman request as TypeError Cannot read property 'xyz' of undefined

Tags: postman-collection-runner

Getting error while running the script in Postman(on newman as well) request as TypeError Cannot read property 'xyz' of undefined.

In my request, i have test script as :

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
tests["Response has data value"] = jsonData.from.xyz === dataAuth.auth;
```

dataAuth is my data file in json is as below :

```
[{
  "path": "auth",
  "id": "test11",
  "desc": "test11",
  "fk": "None",
}]
```

Comment: this is because, in jsonData, there is no data related to `from.xyz`. can you share response body of your request?

Answer (score 0):

This means that a variable is undefined in your tests.